# JNI folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying make helloy-jni app in Android Studio and I have exception

```
06-27 13:17:19.099  12714-12714/com.example.testjni2           E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hello-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.testjni2-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.testjni2-1]: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    at com.example.testjni2.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:9)
    ... 15 more
```

My structure project looks like this

[image: TestJni2Project]

I added my build.gradle line:

```
   compile files('libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so')
```

But this don't helped.
I read [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) and [Android Gradle plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Introduction), but I don't find information about working with jni folder

I am thinking what it [file dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies), but it isn't working

My hello-jni.c file includ

```
jstring  Java_com_example_testjni2_MainActivity_stringFromJNI (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
  }
```

My MainActivity file include

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }
    public native String  stringFromJNI();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String text = stringFromJNI();
        Log.i("MainActivity", text);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My Android.mk file containts

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Tell me, please, where I could make a mistake.

Android Studio 0.1.7
OS - Windows 7 x64

Comment: did builded using NDK tools

Comment: I created .so library used Cygwin Terminal and NDK command /cygdrive/c/Users/%USER_NAME%/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build is this not enough?

Comment: its enough for adding lib

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gradle build system does not support bundling native libraries at the moment. Check https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/nQobKd2Gl_8/Z5yWAvCh4h4J for some custom tasks you'd need to add to your build.gradle.

Note that this is a temporary workaround until gradle supports building native projects.

Comment: Gradle now supports this natively. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 75):

Nowadays there is an easier method than the accepted answer.

All you have to do is create a folder called *"jniLibs"* under your */src/main* directory (ie, /app/src/main/jniLibs) and place your .so files there. It will look like this:

```
app
   |
   src
      |
     main
        |
        jniLibs
            |
            armeabi
            |   |
            |   your_lib_compiled_for_armeabi.so
            |
            armeabi-v7a
            |   |
            |   your_lib_compiled_for_v7a.so
            |
            x86
            |   |
            |   your_lib_compiled_for_x86.so
```

Your .so files should be picked up now.

Comment: It should be `app/src/main/jniLibs`

Comment: @Mussa - yep you saved the days - .so arch dirs have to to go under app/src/main/jniLibs - kudos!

Comment: Maybe you have to change your answer as **Mussa** said. My test is on Android Studio 1.5.

Comment: just adding .so files of all pross architecture without adding any configuration in gradle file ?

Comment: This is awesome, you make my day.

Comment: I am getting this error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Bad JNI version returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/mypath/libfile.so": -4" , I can't show real file name here !!

Comment: Yeah, this isn't working for me. I'm using the latest stable gradle and Android Studio.

Comment: What do we do for x64?

Comment: So no need for compile files('.../libhello-jni.so')?

Answer (score 16):

There is other way to import so to the android project.

1. create the lib dir and armeabi dir like this, and copy so to it.

   |-project

   |--lib

   |----armeabi

   |------libhello-jni.so
2. zip the dir lib.
3. put the zip to the libs dir of project, and change .zip to .jar.
4. add code to the dependencies part of build.gradle.

   compile fileTree(dir:'libs', include:'lib.jar')

Answer (score 12):

add this to your build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs'
    }
}
```

underneath:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the doc about `jniLibs`?

Answer (score 11):

You can add pre built *.so files in Android Studio using gradle 0.7.2+. First create the jniLibs at this location /app/src/main/ location and copy the all the folder with *.so files (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86) in the jniLibs.

As Xavier said same here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/nQobKd2Gl_8/ctDp9viWaxoJ

Answer (score 1):

There is a new way to work with *.so files on gradle 0.7.3
Please check out this link [How to change libs directory in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952388/android-studio-zbar/21284740#21284740)

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to manually create the `jniLibs` directory, here is the official doc of where put native libs .

The official doc is [Android Plugin DSL Reference](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/). See the version of your gradle android plugin version which can be found in Android Studio.

[`sourceSets`](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension:sourceSets(org.gradle.api.Action)) stores the information for resources to compile the app.

[`jniLibs`](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html#com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet:jniLibs) of `sourceSets` is for JNI libs.