# IBM MobileFirst: Not able to initialise JSONStore (Android Native)

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

After copying all the required files which includes .jar and .so files into my app libs/ folder, I'm still receiving the following error (couldn't find "libstlport_shared.so"). Do I need to do anything else to import the files?

[Android Studio App Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLsBh.png)

```
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919): Process: com.app.mfp.mfpapp, PID: 4919
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.saikhuan.mfp.mfpapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.saikhuan.mfp.mfpapp-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libstlport_shared.so"
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:141)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:136)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.openDatabaseIfNecessary(DatabaseManager.java:179)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.checkDatabaseAgainstSchema(DatabaseManager.java:98)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseSchema.isSchemaMismatched(DatabaseSchema.java:417)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.provisionDatabase(WLJSONStore.java:150)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.openCollections(WLJSONStore.java:347)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.openCollections(WLJSONStore.java:372)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.saikhuan.mfp.mfpapp.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:125)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-04 14:27:23.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: MobileFirst version ?

Comment: I'm using MFP version 7.1 on Mac

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating an application on Android Studio you need to specify where the libs folder is located because by default .so files are loaded under the `jniLibs` directory.

For more information you should look at this answer in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29508776/3456790). Also, you can specify the source directory of the `jniLibs` by setting it in your build.gradle file.

```
sourceSets {
   main {
     jniLibs.srcDir = ['libs']
   }
 }
```

within

```
android
{

}
```