# Android Studio 0.2.6 and ZBar project setup

Tags: android, zbar

I am using the latest Android Studio 0.2.6 and the latest ZBar Android SDK.  What I have done so far:

1. Created a brand new project called QRTest
2. Created a folder called libs in my project
3. Put the content of the Zbar libs directory into my project folder
4. Right clicked the zbar.jar file in my project and Added as a Library
5. In my build.gradle file, edited it so that it is now:

   dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
   compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
   }
6. Basically copied the example code from the ZBar android SDK example to my own project.
7. The project compiles and runs fine (0 errors, 0 warnings), but it crashes upon running. The logs show:

> 09-01 16:06:02.026: W/dalvikvm(7050): Exception
> Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing
> Lnet/sourceforge/zbar/ImageScanner;
>
> 09-01 16:06:02.036:
> E/AndroidRuntime(7050): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   209 could not load needed
> library 'libiconv.so' for 'libzbarjni.so' (load_library[1093]: Library
> 'libiconv.so' not found)
>
> 09-01 16:06:02.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7050):
> at net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner.(Unknown Source)

Looking at the code in my MainActivity, it appears to be dying here:

```
 /* Instance barcode scanner */
 scanner = new ImageScanner();
```

Which seems to suggest to me that somehow I havent imported my Zbar library files correctly.  Any help on how to get this very basic example up and going would be appreciated!

Just to note, if I use Android Studio to import a new project from the ZBar Android SDK example, it compiles and runs fine.  However, it is using the old ant build system.  I would rather use the new gradle build system, so thats why I'm trying to import ZBar into a fresh Android 0.2.6 project.  Thanks!

Another note:  I tried modifying my build gradle to the accepted answer here: [How to change libs directory in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952388/android-studio-zbar) and it did not work.

[image]

Comment: Hello I am facing same problem now. Did you figure out how to import zBar to Android Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add *.so libraries to your project. If you use Android Studio and Gradle it's a little complicated because you need to pack libraries into jar. Check my answer here: [ZBar - QR Code Scanner, crashing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524669/zbar-qr-code-scanner-crashing-in-android-studio/20528074#20528074) to see more details.

Answer (score 12):

Solution:

1. Add zbar.jar into app/libs
2. Create a folder called "jniLibs"-Java Native Interface (JNI) under src/main and copy folder armeabi-v7a, armeabi, and x86 into src/main/jniLibs.

The file structure like below:

> src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
>   src/main/jniLibs/armeabi
>   src/main/jniLibs/x86

3. Go to File > Project Structure> app > Dependencies > Add support-v4 into project

Comment: Can one not make use of Gradle?

Comment: You made my day. AWESOME!