# ZBar - QR Code Scanner, crashing in Android Studio

Tags: android, qr-code, zbar-sdk, zbar

I have downloaded from git latest zBar QR Code Scanner (SDK 0.2). I am trying to implement it in my application. I work on Android Studio.

What have I done:

1. I have copied zBar.jar to libs folder of my Project.
2. I have created *.jar files from "amerabi", "amerabi-v7a", "x86" by zip'ing them and changing their format to *.jar.
3. I have copied amerabi.jar, amerabi-v7a.jar and x86.jar to libs folder of my Project.
4. There is no need to change anything in gradle because it is already configured to import every jar file from libs projects. See below:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
       compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'

       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

       compile project(':FacebookSDK')
       compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
       compile project(':Aviary-SDK')
   }
   ```
5. Every class form zBar lib can be seen so I have configured everything. I run my ScannerActivity and in onCreate I get error in this line:

   ```
   scanner = new ImageScanner();  // this line shows an error
   scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
   scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);
   ```

So implementation is 1:1 the same as in example.

My error log:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load zbarjni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/pl.toptof.android.debug-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/pl.toptof.android.debug-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Please help me with that problem. I don't know why my Android Studio can see lib but can't use it in the same way it's used in example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think, you made mistake in your jars structures. If you want to make jar package from *.so libs you should use that kind of structure:

> /lib/armeabi/*.so

It is directory structure example for your library:

```
lib/
---/armeabi
------/libiconv.so
------/libzbarjni.so
```

and of course you should rename final package from lib.zip to armeabi.jar. In your case you should repeat this process for armeabi-v7a and x86.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I can't seem to get this to work and I am having the same issue as @F1sher

Comment: I will, because I have the same problem and he give me correct answer. So if you use Android studio then create 2 folders first one is "lib". Inside lib create "armeabi" folder. Inside armeabi folder put .so files(libiconv.so and libzbarjni.so). then make an archive from lib folder... will be lib.zip for example. After that you will have to rename it into armeabi.jar. Last step is to copy your jar in libs and compile into gradle.

Comment: even I am facing same problem while working on eclipse, project runs on android devices but not on android TV. I followed the above steps, but the jars are going away as soon as I run or build the project.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

The solution is too complicated. What I did to get it working, was to use the jar files already compiled in the example solution from [this example](http://kvenkataprasad.blogspot.dk/2015/01/bar-code-and-qr-code-scanner-example.html). Copy them to your lib folder and make sure to also add them in the gradle file. However, your line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Put the directories *armeabi*, *armeabi-v7a*, and *x86* in a sub-directory called *native-libs* under your root project folder.
Then add these settings to your **build.gradle** file:

```
android {
    // other settings
    sourceSets {
            main {
                jni.srcDirs=[] //to suppress makefiles autogeneration
                jniLibs.srcDirs=['native-libs'] //native *.so in armeabi x86 and mips to include
            }
        }
}
```

The resulting .apk should have the native libs included now.

Answer (score 1):

You better check if you have the newest possible version of ZBar in dependencies in your app.gradle file. Getting the latest version worked for me and solved all the problems like failing to find libzbarjni.so and libiconv.so

Comment: For me with `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.3'` I keep on getting the error

Comment: And do you have "compile 'net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0'" in your app.gradle? I have these plus  compileSdkVersion 25, minSdkVersion 16, buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" and it worked for me. I didn't have to add anything extra.

Comment: I did not have this dependency, but now I added it and the problem still remains. Can you share your whole build,gradle so that I can compare?

Comment: Sure. You can find it here. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wc2nz75sxyxu8bc/build.gradle?dl=0

Comment: By the way on which device was your application crashing? I have one Galaxy Nexus observing the problem on my side in my app.

Comment: I had problems on Asus Zenphone (version 6.0) and on some other devices with android version 6 or higher. A had this issue a long ago, but it worked fine with android 4.0.3 and 5.0.0 as I remember.

Comment: Today i did another experiment I created an emulator running API 17. It crashes with the same error as my real phone. I know I have already given you too much work, but is it possible that you check with such and see if your application will run ok on such an emulator

Comment: After much of fight, adding this line ` System.loadLibrary("iconv");` before loading the `ScannerView` made the error go away for me. Using zbar 1.9.3

Comment: Happy for you:) Don't forget about asking for permissions and it will work like a charm