# ZBar crashing Android Studio

Tags: java, android, zbar, libs

I'm trying to use the ZBar libraries in my project on Android Studio. 
I copy the `armeabi` `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` folders inside libs folder of my project. I also copy the `zbar.jar` file inside libs.

The `MainActivity` and `CameraPreview` files are corect.

When I compile the project, the app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load iconv from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.coster.barcode-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/it.coster.barcode-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Comment: check and ensure that in the armeabi folders, you have the libiconv.so and libzbarjni.so

Comment: yes those files are inside.

Comment: ok..didn't see android studio - check possible duplicate.. [zbar-qr-code-scanner-crashing-in-android-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524669/zbar-qr-code-scanner-crashing-in-android-studio/20528074#20528074)

Comment: just tried... didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Write following line in your activity file to load manually load library

```
System.loadLibrary( "iconv" );
```

Comment: Add this line before setContentView() method in onLoad()